Git pull from code commit repo is not working in EC2 Linux Instance
I have an existing git repo on code commit and existing ec2 instance of linux.
After the SSH setup when I try git pull command then I am getting error of permission denied.
From ssh://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<my-repo>
 * branch            stage      -> FETCH_HEAD
error: unable to unlink old '.gitignore': Permission denied
error: unable to create file '<to>/<folder>/index.html'.html: Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old '<to>/<folder>/index2.html': Permission denied

Things I have tried:

This directory is owned by any other user other than ubuntu and I changed owner to ubuntu then also its not working.
Gave 777 permission to the directory and also for the .git directory
Following the document from aws to make and setup the connection and when I created new instance and new repo I am able to pull, but In existing ec2 instance its not working.

Tried to follow the answer here and not worked also tried this.
Any help would be appreciated
I want to make pull from the repo and then running the deploy script which include pulling from codecommit

You said you gave 777 permission to the directory, but was that recursive?

Yes! I tried that too.
